# Fill circles partially for custom coin-slider

Tags: css, html, canvas

I want to design a custom coin-slider where while going through a certain range of images represented by a particular coin, the coin's 'filled' factor should vary from 0 to 1. Say when the range is 10 images, and I am in the 3rd image, it should look like (the filled up coins represent previous ranges already traversed, while the empty ones towards the end represent the ranges yet to be touched upon. The 6th circle from the left is of interest here):

[image]

How do I generate such circle images? Is there some CSS tricks available? Or perhaps with HTML5 canvas?

Comment: The normal way to do that would be to have one image with say five or six circles in various stages of being filled.  Each coin in the display is its own image using that sprite as a background, and then use jQuery to change the offsets of each in turn to fill the coins sequentially.

Comment: Right. I got the idea. Thanks mate.

Comment: An alternative would be to superimpose a `div`, with a partially white, partially transparent (the holes) background image, over another `div`, with the solid orange background. The "stencil" background image can just be set to `x-repeat`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go as css as you can, you may want to try to set a bunch of 10 divs.
If you set border-radius to 50%, they get circles.
then you set all of them a border of the choosen color

and if you set the first 6 circles a specific class, and associate a background-color to that, you have the filled circles.